# Wave synthesizer software

Tags: sound-effects, software, synthesizer

I would like to know if there is a software that can generate a waveform where I can adjust modulation and pitch visually over time. I'm trying to make basic animal sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most well featured modern synths allow you to do this. Look out for graphical enveloped such as these in Absynth:

[image]

Absynth might be a good choice for you.

I'd also check [Andy Farnell's](http://www.obiwannabe.co.uk/tutorials/html/tutorials_main.html) work in PureData in this area too. If you want to get into this seriously, then being able to patch custom systems is really a must (imho).

Answer (score 0):

There are two good wavetable synthesizers:

1) Absynth: http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/synths/absynth-5/

2) Waves Wavetable Synthesizer: http://www.waves.com/plugins/codex#codex-synth-in-depth-tutorial

I have used both and both are absolutely amazing!